# Unable to resolve column 'uid'

Tags: php, sql, phpstorm

I have cut the code from one file, created a new file and pasted that code into the new file.

My code includes that line:

```
$query = $this->matchDao->rawSQL("SELECT uid FROM $table WHERE $sqlColumn IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ABS($sqlColumn - $val) LIMIT 2");
```

PhpStorm gives me that error:

> Unable to resolve column 'uid'

How comes? In my other file it's all good and I don't get this error.

Comment: You are telling PhpStorm to look at uid column in `$table` but because `$table` is a variable, it can't be assessed until the code is executed. So simply ignore these errors. You can reduce their "error score" in the PHPStorm preferences.

Comment: what is your "other file"?

Comment: @Martin the other file has exactly the same code but has just another class name. just wondering why I don't get the same error in the other file.

Comment: Cannot suggest anything concrete without knowing much more info about files/tech/setup. But overall Martin is correct -- IDE does not really play well with dynamic table names. It supports some cases, but only some of them. If it's the same content and files are next to each other, then they should be treated in a same manner.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why the one 1 file shows me the error and the other file does not.

But my solution was using the [@lang annotation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-language-injections.html#use-lang-annotation) and the error was gone.

```
$query = $this->matchDao->rawSQL( /** @lang text */ "SELECT uid FROM $table WHERE $sqlColumn IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ABS($sqlColumn - $val) LIMIT 2");
```

Comment: well that's because you're telling PHPStorm not to approach that text as SQL.